# Form abrindo popup JS em branco

Tags: javascript

Preciso que retornar o resultado da submissão de um form em um popup(tentei lightbox mas penei pra conseguir usar, seria até melhor, recomendações?) no centro da tela do usuário, o único problema é que o popup tá retornando uma página em branco e eu não consegui identificar onde está o erro no código.

Se eu colocar 'include/verifica.php' no window.open ele dá várias mensagens de erro, não resolve.

Form:

```
<form action="include/verifica.php" onsubmit="return abrirPopup('this', 400, 120)" method="POST">
```

JS:

```js
function abrirPopup(form, w, h) {
  var newW = w + 100;
  var newH = h + 100;
  var left = (screen.width - newW) / 2;
  var top = (screen.height - newH) / 2;
  var newwindow = window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=' + newW + ',height=' + newH + ',left=' + left + ',top=' + top);
  form.target = 'formpopup';
  newwindow.resizeTo(newW, newH);

  //posiciona o popup no centro da tela
  newwindow.moveTo(left, top);
  newwindow.focus();
  return false;
}
```

O formulário tá na minha index, ele verifica se todos os dados foram inseridos na verifica.php em caso positivo ele inclui a insere.php que é quem joga os dados pro banco de dados e me retorna um número de protocolo, que é a id da nova linha na table.

Desculpa a bagunça do código mas isso se dá na maior parte pela quantidade de vezes que eu já alterei ele no desespero de tentar arrumar haha

Answer (score 2):

está faltando colocar o endereço da popup em

```
var newwindow = window.open('ENDEREÇODAPOP', 'formpopup', 'width=' + newW + ',height=' + newH + ',left=' + left + ',top=' + top);
```

Comment: Ai que tá, se eu coloco o endereço, verifica.php ou insere.php ele me retorna erros como esse: Notice: Undefined index: data_coleta in C:\Arquivos de programas\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\sistemas\projeto\include\verifica.php on line 13

Comment: mas esse erro é da pagina verifica.php, vc já abriu essa página diretamente no navegador?

Comment: e o que tem nessa linha 13?

Comment: isso tá estranho, ou abre a pop e a action do form não funciona, ou a action funciona e não abre a pop

Comment: A sua pergunta não seria: Ao enviar o formulário para include/verifica.php, retornar o resultado da submissão desse form em um popup nessa include/verifica.php?

Comment: Quando o form manda abrir em uma nova aba o cadastro completa perfeitamente. 

Os dois erros que tenho:
1- Se não há target no window.open o popup abre em branco.
2- Se o target to popup é alguma das duas páginas do processo de cadastro(verifica.php e insere.php) o popup abre com erro(imagino que não processe adequadamente o conteúdo delas).